# Seems like I cant control 4 stepper motor at once

Tags: esp32, stepper-motor

Im trying to control 4 stepper motors with the AccelStepper library.

Something like this:

```
AccelStepper FL(1,stepPin,dirPin);
AccelStepper FR(1,stepPin2,dirPin2);
AccelStepper BL(1,stepPin3,dirPin3);
//AccelStepper BR(1,stepPin4,dirPin4);
```

The problem is, It works just fine if I declare 3 instance of the AccelStepper, but once I uncomment the 4th one there's an error.

```
Error message: Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows Store 1.8.42.0) (Windows 10), Board: "ESP32 Dev Module, Disabled, Default, 240MHz (WiFi/BT), QIO, 80MHz, 4MB (32Mb), 921600, None"




In file included from C:\Users\Parit\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.1/tools/sdk/include/esp32/xtensa/xtruntime.h:30:0,

                 from C:\Users\Parit\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.1/tools/sdk/include/freertos/freertos/portmacro.h:80,

                 from C:\Users\Parit\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.1/tools/sdk/include/freertos/freertos/portable.h:94,

                 from C:\Users\Parit\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.1/tools/sdk/include/freertos/freertos/FreeRTOS.h:105,

                 from C:\Users\Parit\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.1\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:32,

                 from sketch\Test_file.ino.cpp:1:

C:\Users\Parit\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.1/tools/sdk/include/esp32/xtensa/config/specreg.h:40:13: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 #define BR  4

             ^

C:\Users\Parit\Desktop\Test_file\Test_file.ino:31:14: note: in expansion of macro 'BR'

 AccelStepper BR(1,stepPin4,dirPin4);

              ^

Multiple libraries were found for "WiFi.h"

 Used: C:\Users\Parit\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.1\libraries\WiFi

 Not used: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.42.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries\WiFi

exit status 1

Error compiling for board ESP32 Dev Module.



This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Im not sure if the problem is the ESP 32 or the code. I use the A4988 driver to connect with all 4 stepper motors.

Comment: Please show the complete error message

Comment: Not in the comments please. You can add this information to your question by editing it

Comment: ok sorry, i'll add it now

Answer (score 1):

The variable name `BR` is already used somewhere else.

Use a different variable name

```
AccelStepper FL(1,stepPin,dirPin);
AccelStepper FR(1,stepPin2,dirPin2);
AccelStepper BL(1,stepPin3,dirPin3);
AccelStepper BackRight(1,stepPin4,dirPin4);
```

Comment: Thank you ! It's working now. But it's weird, I can confirm that I haven't used a variable with that name any where in my code/

Comment: It's explained in the error message. It says BR is defined as a constant with value `4` (` #define BR  4`)

Comment: Alright, but still, I didn't write  "#define BR 4" In my code. Anyways, it's working now so it doesn't matter, Thanks.

Comment: The first definition necessarily in your code - it may be in one of the libraries your code included.

Comment: According to the error message it's inside the file `specreg.h`. Try reading the error messages you get. They contain a lot more information than you'd think. They can be a bit overwhelming at first, but after a few of them you'll get a feel for what's relevant, and what to look for.